# Ruby - replace the first occurrence of a substring with another string

Tags: ruby, string, replace

`a = "foobarfoobarhmm"`

I want the output as `"fooBARfoobarhmm"

ie only the first occurrence of "bar" should be replaced with "BAR".

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use `#sub`:

```
a.sub('bar', "BAR")
```

Answer (score 18):

`String#sub` is what you need, as Yossi already said. But I'd use a Regexp instead, since it's faster:

```
a = 'foobarfoobarhmm'
output = a.sub(/foo/, 'BAR')
```

Comment: I just did a benchmark and regex takes 50% longer than just using a string as parameter for sub.

Comment: I checked it, and the Regexp version is faster. I used MRI 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 2.0.0 and even JRuby, all of them being faster on the Regexp version. The benchmark code: https://gist.github.com/tbuehlmann/5574713

Wanna provide your benchmark?

Comment: Hmmmm. I must apologize for my assertion, it seems I made an error in my benchmark. The regex actually is faster.

Comment: That's not very intuitive. I would expect a regex to be slower than a specialised method.

Comment: In my opinion (IMO), when you don't need a regex, the string version is more readable.

Comment: @NielsB. yeah, perhaps Ruby's performance can be improved here.

Comment: @NielsB. RegEx engines vary greatly on their level of optimization. String parsing has a wide spectrum of efficiency from horrible to impressive. RegEx can be on both ends.

Answer (score 11):

to replace the first occurrence, just do this:

```
str = "Hello World"
str['Hello'] = 'Goodbye'
# the result is 'Goodbye World'
```

you can even use regular expressions:

```
str = "I have 20 dollars"
str[/\d+/] = 500.to_s
# will give 'I have 500 dollars'
```

Comment: `500.to_s` is sometimes written `"500"`. :-)

Comment: I wrote it like that intentionally. to indicate that you need to assign an explicit string. Because the conversion is not automatic here. If you do this instead `str[/\d+/] = 500` you'll get an error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String` .