# Java replace only first occurrence of a substring in a string

Tags: java, string, replace

This is somehow a duplicate of this problem [Ruby - replace the first occurrence of a substring with another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963394/ruby-replace-the-first-occurrence-of-a-substring-with-another-string) just in java.

Problem is:

I have a string: `"ha bla ha ha"`

Now I want to replace the first (and only the first) `"ha"` with `"gurp"`:

```
"gurp bla ha ha"
```

`string.replace("ha", "gurp")` doesn't work, as it replaces all `"ha"`s.

Comment: Did you read about `String#replaceFirst`? or if you don't want to use regex [StringUtils#replaceOnce(..)][1][1]:(http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceOnce(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String))

Comment: It is very useful to read javadoc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [the `replaceFirst` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).  It uses a regular expression, but the literal sequence `"ha"` still works.

```
string.replaceFirst("ha", "gurp");
```

Comment: But what if you want to replace a literal dot? The OP's example is a toy one, not reflective of real world edge cases.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat "\\."

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) (available since Java 1.4), it does just what you need:

```
string = string.replaceFirst("ha", "gurp");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use already tested and well documented libraries in favor of writing your own code!

```
StringUtils.replaceOnce("aba", "a", "")    = "ba"
```

(copied from How to replace string only once without regex in Java?)