# Java Replacing one word in a string from a text file

Tags: java, javafx

So i have a confing file here is an example from that file

```
<STX><ESC>F16<LF>vartest<ETX>
```

After reading the config file i need to create a new file but in that new file i should replace the "vartest" with an actual string. What would be the easiest way to do this.

I read the file like this

```
line17 = scan.nextLine();
```

Write it like this

```
bufferW.write(line17);
bufferW.newLine();
```

JDK11 // IntelliJ IDE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java replace only first occurrence of a substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916881/java-replace-only-first-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`String#replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), this replaces `vartest` in your `line17` string with `mynewstring`, ofcourse this can be whatever you want:

```
line17 = line17.replace("vartest", "mynewstring");

// Alternatively using a variable instead

line17 = line17.replace("vartest", myStringVariable);
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch :)